# Practice Makes Perfect median

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hey :) I'm newbie to python and I'm wondering how to delete square brackets from my return output. I get an error Oops, try again. median([1]) returned **[1]** instead of 1. How to delete these square brackets? Is the rest of code OK or does it need changes?
This is my code:

```
def median(List):
    newlist = []
    for num in List:
        newlist.append(num)
    return newlist
    newlist.sort()

    if len(newlist) % 2 == 1:
        return float(newlist[len(newlist) / 2])
    else:
        return float((newlist[len(newlist) / 2] + newlist[len(newlist) / 2 + 1])) / 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line:

```
return newlist
```

That's returning a copy of the list and then not executing the rest of your function.

**EDIT**

A big issue with your current code is that you're choosing the wrong indices when the array is an even length. (For a length-4 array, you're averaging elements 2 and 3, when you should be averaging elements 1 and 2.)

A couple other small suggestions:

1. Use `sorted(...)` to get a sorted copy of a list.
2. Use `//` for integer division so your code works properly with Python 3 (as well as Python 2).
3. Use "snake case" (lowercaes with underscores between words) for variable names.

Updated code:

```
def median(lst):
    new_list = sorted(lst)

    if len(new_list) % 2 == 1:
        return float(new_list[len(new_list) // 2])
    else:
        return (new_list[len(new_list) // 2 - 1] +
                new_list[len(new_list) // 2]) / 2.0
```

Comment: Thanks for fast and accurate reply! One more question about this part of Your answer: " (For a length-4 array, you're averaging elements 2 and 3, when you should be averaging elements 1 and 2.)". I should average element 1 and 2 because indexing in list is exactly the same like indexing in string, is that correct what I'm saying? if I have something like that : lst = [2, 4, 7, 10] I mean that the first integer in my list has index 0, right? Actually, there is one more thing about Your suggestions, why using 'snake case' is so important? Don't get me wrong, I am just curious ;)

Comment: Exactly, array indices start at 0. Snake case is just the style convention of the Python community. Using it will make your code easier to read for other Python developers.

Comment: Okay, thanks for answer :) Which course of python, do you recommend me to start after I finish Codecademy course?

Comment: @Konradek Sorry, no idea... it's been a long time since I first learned. :-)